# How do i make my IP public, Externally can access my localhost

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, web-hosting, ubuntu-server

I just want to make my IP public, so that it can be accessed from any where.I am using `ubuntu 18.04`. Already installed apache2 and PHP. The index file located in `/var/www/html/example.com/public_html/index.php`. In local host it is running and with in the same network i am able to access my website. Also made some changes in firewall.

here is my `/etc/hosts` file configuration

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       amal

127.0.0.1       www.example.com
127.0.0.1       example.com
```

And `etc/apache2/sites-avaliable/example.com.conf` file configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName      www.example.com
        ServerAlias     example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
        ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

with this configuration i am able to access this webpages with my IP(192.168.255.24) any locally connected device.
Now i want to public my IP and can access these webpages from anywhere, I don't know much about this. I followed some tutorials but failed.
This is Firewall status

command

```
ufw status

outputStatus: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

And in my jiofi router portforward included my `192.168.255.24` with port `80`
but when ever i tried to access my website with the global IP, got from `canyouseeme.org` it displays `The connection has timed out`. How to solve this problem please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

192.168.255.24 is a private ip, it cannot be accessed from the internet only from the intranet.

127.0.0.1: loopback address, only accessible from the same device (computer) it is like saying myself. If somene else says myself, it is not you any more.

To access you computer on an intranet from the internet, you will need to get your public address, you can do this by googling "which is my ip", just take note that most likely it is a dynamic address which may change every now and then.

This will be the address to use from outside of the intranet (from inside it most likely not work)

Second, you have to go into the configuration of the router connected to the internet and:

- Reserv in the DHCP a specific address for the coputer hosting the webserver (I guess it would be 192.168.255.24 ). You need to do this for the computer to have always the same ip address in the intranet.
- Configure port forwarding (also in the router) to redirect what is received on port 80 and if you will be using ssl port 443 for example to the reserved addresses (192.168.255.24 ) on port 80 and 443 respectively. In this way what comes in from the internet on ports 80 and 443 goes to the computer hosting the web server on the same port.

Third, you will need to check the computer's firewall rules to enable traffic on port 80.

Just a note of advice, when you enable the port forwarding in the router you are explicitly letting computers from the Internet access your intranet on the specific ports. I understand this is what you want, but I just wanted to make it clear.

Comment: Sir in my router don't have the option DHCP, But it always gives the same IP inintranet(192.168.255.24).  And i checked my public Keeps changing. and already configured port forwarding with port 80and IP (192.168.225.24)

Comment: I don't think the public ip changes that quickly. Ussually you will have it assigned for at least a few days. You can also get the current ip address from the internet facing router in the configuration. Where wan status is. O where it says if it is connected to the internet or not.